# No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "********" with a private key was found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

I am performing the following in order to generate production certificate and provisioning profile.

1. I make a certificate request with "Request a Certificate from Certificate Authority With..." from the Keychain.
2. Then I go to developer.apple.com to **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles** and create a new production certificate. (Certificates -> Production -> + sign Production -> App Store and Ad Hoc). I include the certificate request from point 1, generate the certificate and download it. Then I double-click to load in keychain.
3. I generate a provisioning profile and include the certificate from point 2 in it. Then I download it and double click it. It appears in Xcode, but I get: No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "********" with a private key was found.

I see the certificate and the private key in the keychain. What could be the problem? (I followed the same steps for development certificate and provisioning profile and it works)

Comment: Do you have the option "Automatically manage signing" enable?

Comment: download manual profiles from acode->preferences.

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez I don't have Automatically manage signing enabled. If I enable it, I get the error when trying to upload to App Store.

Comment: Which is exactly the AppStore error?

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez I don't have the error anymore, so I cannot say what it was. Thanks.

Comment: @ShivamTripathi I did this and now it works. Also restarted my machine so maybe this has to do with it also somehow. Not sure but thank you.

Comment: @Shivam Tripathi this worked, but I had to restart XCode (12) for the error to disappear